# Worklight: Can a user with the javaee appcenteruser role access the appcenter console

Tags: security, console, app-store, ibm-mobilefirst

I currently have a demo worklight 6.1 server that is running on a Liberty profile.  There is no ldap integration.  I have defined the appcenteruserrole in the server.xml file.  I have also defined the appcenterusergroup which belongs to the appcenteruserrole.  I also have created a user, "testuser" which belongs to the appcenterusergroup.  The appcenteruser role    is bound to both the appcenterconsole.war and the applicationcenter.war applications.  The user "testuser can access the AppCenter catalog from the IBM App Center mobile app, however if I try to login to the application center console from a browser (hostname:9080/appcenterconsole/login.html) with userid of testuser, the login fails with the message, "User not authorized to log in to the console".  Is this working as designed, where only users that belong to the appcenteradmin role can access the application center from a browser?  Thanks!
JT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is working as designed, only users with the appcenteradmin role are authorized to open the administration console.

Emmanuel